# Paragraph next to image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the text to line up correctly next to my image. This is what I have tried but it is throwing the text off making the spacing very unpleasant to the eye. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<p><img src="../../images/stop.jpg" style="width:40px;height:40px;">Your transaction requires special instructions from our office.  Please complete this Special Handling form, and we will contact you within three business days to provide assistance.  Please do not complete this mail packet until you receive our instructions.  Thank you!</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd float the image to the left with a little CSS, which allows the text to float up next to it:

```css
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="../../images/stop.jpg" style="width:40px;height:40px;">Your transaction requires special instructions from our office. Please complete this Special Handling form, and we will contact you within three business days to provide assistance. Please do not complete this mail packet until you receive our instructions.
  Thank you!</p>
```

Comment: theres other images on the page though can I give it an id?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Much better to use a class, which is reusable.

Comment: @isherwood - unless Zane doesn't intend to reuse it.

Comment: It's still a good practice. IDs should be a last resort in CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code.

```
p img{float:left;margin:0 10px 10px 10px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sobxf85t/

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to put the text and the image in a table, in the same row, the image would be in the first column, while the text goes to the second column in the first row .
here's the code

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><img src="../../images/stop.jpg" style="width:40px;height:40px;"/></td>
     <td><p>Your transaction requires special instructions from our office.  Please complete this Special Handling form, and we will contact you within three business days to provide assistance.  Please do not complete this mail packet until you receive our instructions.  Thank you!</p></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```